# Unable to access jarfile using Ant

Tags: java, ant

I'am not able to run the jar file by using ant build.xml

```
<property name="src.dir" value="src"/>

<property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
<property name="jar.dir" value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>

<property name="main-class" value="org.ant.SimpleAnt"/>

<target name="clean" >
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>


<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"/>

</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java jar="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.SampleAnt}.jar" fork="true"/>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean, jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean, run"/>
```

What is the proper way of executing jar file using the ant?

Comment: what's the error/exception message?

Comment: Not much to go on here, but your jar create uses `${ant.project.name}`, whereas the run uses `${ant.project.SampleAnt}` for the jar name.  Also the main class is called `org.ant.SimpleAnt` which is similar to SampleAnt - possibly intended, but maybe not.